# Creating build under source control

Tags: build, branch

I am trying to get over with my base structure to manage adopting alm practices.

First I have done structuring for my source folder structure where under my main branch I did put folder as builds. I was intending to store my builds (ci, nigthly, manual) be stored under each branch. However while I was creating a new build definition I stuck with a field.

1. Build agent folder under workspace definition should I leave it as it is `$SourceDir` my source control and build server are reside on same machine.
2. Drop folder is not the same this as builds folder in my source control, right? I mean should I keep the new builds under source control or ci server will handle it itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no benefit to storing your build output in version control but if your process dictates this there's nothing stopping you from doing it.  You'd need to customize the build process template to achieve this as part of the automated build.  Out of the box each build will create a label of the source (accessible against several workitem types) and assuming everything is setup correctly you can pull a copy of this build from the drop location on the build server.

The build server will have it's own workspace definition for which `$SourceDir` will map to the top level directory where the source will be pulled from version control.  The Drop folder is where the final build output will be placed.  It can be any local or UNC file share accessible to the account under which the builds are running.

Drop folder isn't related to yours or the build servers local workspace folder so even if you set this as the drop folder it won't get added to version control.  Remember that your local  workspace just provides a level of abstraction over the physical structure of your version control structure on the server.  Simply mapping them one to one locally won't in anyway cause artifacts added to the local to be automatically added to the server.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: preliminary thanks for your input and giving clarification. here is another naive question. i kind a trying stick to whatever was recommended so I mainly see folks are keeping build folder under source control. do they save buildtypes or build output. I try to save my build types but could not find a way to give a path it always keep appearing somewhere different.

Comment: Please show us where you have ever seen anyone keep the build folders under source control. I have _never_ seen this done, as it makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: John here it is  already put in other place you must be ignored or this post is redundant  [stackoverflow.com/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684685/organizing-source-code-in-tfs-2010/2782463#2782463). mr hinsh has whole series of articles on branching and building. [blog.mrhinsh..](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/guidance-how-to-layout-you-files-for-an-ideal-solution/). again my bad if violated the space of wisdom.believe me it s kind obscure for me. books are very brief since they are covering a lot of topic in range of 600 pages.